# Change or add connection string in the App.config programmatically using MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, app-config

Is is possible to add or change connection in the connection string in the App.config, programmatically?
I've tried something with

```
    var A = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
    A.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings());
```

but i got a message that it's read only.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any modification to the configuration file of a web application requires IIS to restart. As such, you cannot make a runtime modification to the file from your code because it would require restarting the entire application.

Comment: Yes, this is simply because of how IIS manages configuration values.